# Reading a hexadecimal value from a text file

Tags: fortran, hex

I want to read some sort of values from a text file in Fortran 90
for example a file which includes "1FD". I can read this value from screen, but when I am trying to read it from file some error has occurred.
could anyone give me an example?

```
program ReadSomeHex

  implicit none

  character(4) :: Hexval

  integer      :: Decval   

  Open(1,File='Input.txt')

  Open(2,File='Output.txt')


  read(1,*) Hexval

  Decval =  Z'Hexval'

  write(2,*) Decval


end program ReadSomeHex
```

Comment: This is my code:
program ReadSomeHex
implicit none

character(4) :: Hexval
integer      :: Decval   

Open(1,File='Input.txt')
Open(2,File='Output.txt')


read(1,*) Hexval

Decval =  Z'Hexval'

write(2,*) Decval


end program ReadSomeHex
 
For example in a txt file i put 
2F5

Comment: Please put the code into the question...

Comment: So, how i change this program to work in FORTRAN:

program ReadSomeHex
implicit none

character(4) :: Hexval
integer      :: Decval   

Open(1,File='Input.txt')
Open(2,File='Output.txt')


read(1,*) Hexval

Decval =  Z'Hexval'

write(2,*) Decval


end program ReadSomeHex

Comment: The file has been attached

Comment: @Mortezanamvar No, that's not the way to go. Edit the question and enter the code! I'm not going to load some RAR from some suspicious site...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a hexa format specifier in fortran. If your `Input.txt` starts literally with `1FD`, then

```
read(1,'(Z4)') Decval
write(2,*) Decval
```

will directly read `1FD` interpreted as a hexadecimal value into `Decval`, i.e. the value of `Decval` will be `509`.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you Sir.

Comment: Glad to have helped. If I solved your problem, please consider accepting my answer.